# How to upload to image hosting site in java?

Tags: java, upload, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload image to a image hosting site (fastpic.ru) but I can't get right response as I expected. I used fiddler to check would I send right param and everything seems are fine but I can't get right response. Could you guide me how to upload and get response in proper way?

Right response I mean I should receive something like http://fastpic.ru/session/2012/0425/Y6sEtGjtT1.html but I only receive http://fastpic.ru/index.php

Thank you

This is my code

```
    String urlToConnect = "http://fastpic.ru/uploadmulti";
    String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Generate random boundary
    URLConnection connection = new URL(urlToConnect).openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // This sets request method to POST.
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    OutputStream output = null;
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        output = connection.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8"), true); // true = Autoflush, important!

        writer.println("-----------------------------" + boundary);
        writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[]\"; filename=\"" + fileToUpload.getName() + "\"");
        writer.println("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        writer.println();
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(fileToUpload);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            output.flush();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {
                }
            }
        }
        writer.println();

        writer.println("-----------------------------" + boundary);
        writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"submit\"");
        writer.println();
        writer.println("Загрузить");

        writer.println("-----------------------------" + boundary);
        writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploading\"");
        writer.println();
        writer.println("1");
        writer.println("-----------------------------" + boundary + "--");

    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                connection.getInputStream()));
    String decodedString;
    while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(decodedString);
    }
    in.close();
```

Comment: ok I see thumb down here. May be you think that I have not researched before asking but the fact that I tried in 1 day without result. So at least give me what article/post I should read to learn. Thank you

Comment: *"... I can't get right response as I expected ..."* is pretty useless as it stands.

Comment: You should improve your question by stating more precisely what doesn't go according to your expectations, and what result you want. Your question is too vague and the code too long.

Comment: OK, I explained more about right response in the question and remove some lines. Could you view it again? @mario-de-schaepmeester

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't returning the right output, there is probably something incorrect with the input.

I would recommend using the Apache HTTP components, such as `MultipartEntity` at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html for POSTing this kind of data. If you're trying to manually encode your data, it would be quite easy to make a simple mistake that'll stop the entire thing from working. There are a lot of examples using the Apache components, and its pretty simple to use.

Comment: I used fiddle to compare input data between my application and browser upload and both are the same except boundary. The problem is I don't know what's wrong in my code so I hope some can indicate what's wrong and point me to right way. BTW I will look in apache http components